# Control the run order of Eloquent scopes

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent, query-builder

I have a simple Eloquent scope that I would like to always run after all the other "Where" statements in the final query to optimize the efficiency of the query.  I would like it to run last, no matter where I put it in the query builder (it's for a large application where this scope has been used many times, and I'd like it to be fool-proof in the future)

I'll put the scope below, but it's exactly the same as the example in the Eloquent documentation.

```
    public function scopeActive($query)
    {
        $query->where('active', 1);
    }
```

I know eloquent is smart enough to put ordering statements after Where statements, so maybe there's a trick to use that logic to manipulate the order of the where statements, but so far I can't see it.  I'm using MySQL if there's some kind of raw sql I can run.

Comment: Check out https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent#global-scopes

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT ...
    WHERE foo > 123
      AND active = 1
```

will [probably] run *faster* if you have

```
INDEX(active, foo)
```

Note that, regardless of where `active=1` is in the `WHERE` clause, putting `active` _first`in the`INDEX` is optimal.

My point here is "always run after other Wheres" is not the proper goal to try to achieve.  So...

I don't know if Eloquent can 'automatically' add such a statement, but maybe we can achieve the equivalent goal inside MySQL.  (There are a hundred frameworks that try to hide MySQL from the user.  I cannot learn them all; instead, I try to help users work around the framework deficiencies.  The framework user needs to learn *both* the framework *and* the underlying database.)

- Create a `VIEW` on top of the `TABLE`, where the `VIEW`: `SELECT * FROM tbl WHERE active = 1`.  Then tell Eloquent to access that View instead of the underlying Table.  (I suspect the framework's syntax is the same.)
- Add `active,` to the *beginning* of most of the indexes for the *table*  (Views cannot be indexes.)

If you need to discuss this further (either before or after making such changes), please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` and `EXPLAIN SELECT...`  There could be other issues make my advice not as good as I hope.